# Allow visitors to search by multiple tags (specific IDs)

Tags: tags

I'm trying to create a search form/filter that allows visitors to search by specific tags.

I've implemented this solution:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<fieldset>

<input type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="search…" maxlength="50" required="required" />

<p>Refine search to posts containing chosen tags:</p>

<?php
// generate list of tags

$tags = get_tags();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {

echo

    '<label>',
    '<input type="checkbox" name="taglist[]" value="',  $tag->slug, '" /> ',
    $tag->name,
    "</label>\n";

}
?>

<button type="submit">Search</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And this is in functions.php to make it work:

```
// advanced search functionality
function advanced_search_query($query) {if($query->is_search()) {

// tag search

if (isset($_GET['taglist']) && is_array($_GET['taglist'])) {
$query->set('tag_slug__and', $_GET['taglist']); }

return $query; }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query', 1000);
```

However, it displays ALL tags. How would I get specific tags by ID for visitors to select?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

**1)** First, make sure you are using WordPress 4.3, which was just released, or this won't work.

**2)** Second, drop the entire `pre_get_posts` hook, you won't need it. WordPress will automatically filter the search archive based on the terms you've included in the querystring (this is the 4.3 functionality I just mentioned).

**3)** Next, replace your call to `$tags = get_tags()` with the following…

```
$tags = get_tags(
    array(
        'include' => array( 1, 17, 22 )
    )
);
```

Simply change the `include => array()` array to use only the tag/term ids you want… alternatively, you might instead change `include` to `exclude` to show *everything* EXCEPT the tags you specify.

**4)** Finally, change the name of your checkbox inputs to `tag[]`.

## What We Did

The premise is this: WordPress 4.3 will automatically filter an archive page (including search results) based an array of querystring values you pass to it. This includes, for instance, "tag".

So, we can tell the `get_tags()` function to fetch only specific tags that we specify. It takes an associative array as an argument, and one of those is `include`, which takes another array of only the tag ids you want it to return.

To tie it all together, we need to make sure that the form is building the appropriate query string that WordPress expects. Something like `yoursite.com/blog/?s=your+search+terms&tag%5B%5D=foo&tag%5B%5D=bar`

To achieve that, we just make sure that the checkboxes have the name `tag[]` - which will be formatted by the querystring correctly, and then caught by WordPress which will use it to filter the search results.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Matt! :-)

When I do that, it doesn't show anything. Do I need to modify the functions.php part?

Comment: Actually, you can remove it entirely. If your querystring is properly formatted, WordPress will filter the search results by the provided terms automatically. That's probably why you're getting nothing.

Comment: I guess the part I'm messing up is when I replace it with that, then the labeling doesn't appear because I overwrite it with the code you gave?

Sorry, total amateur here.

Comment: I expanded the answer with a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: Matt, you are AWESOME!

If I can every repay the favor, please let me know!

I did get a weird error on the search results page that I'm trying to figure out: "preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given"

Is there any way to donate money to you/pay you for this?

Comment: I think I got, it I changed the input from "tag[]" to just "tag" and the search results worked. :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it, Jeremia! Have you updated to WordPress 4.3 yet? It's only a couple days old, but previous versions are unable to parse taxonomy term arrays in the querystring (they expect a csv list, which isn't directly compatible with HTML forms). Leaving out the `[]` will mean WordPress will only filter the last checked value instead of all of them.

Comment: Yeah, I just updated but when I had those brackets it was throwing me that error:  "preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given"

Comment: Damn, I wrote the patch for that in 4.3, so that means I may have missed something.

Comment: Yeah, if you need to see the page just let me know.

Comment: So, is it a mistake on my end?

Comment: No, I've confirmed it. The patch works with custom taxonomies, but WordPress core still gives tags and categories special treatment, and it looks like I'll have to submit a patch that fixes multiple other areas to get tags and categories behaving the same. FYI, chances are, this fix won't make release until WordPress 4.4.

Comment: Jeremia, I've submitted a patch to WordPress core. If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as correct. You can find my patch submission on the official WordPress issue tracker here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33532

Comment: Thanks Matt, so just wait until 4.4 then right?

Comment: Right. The patch has already been accepted, so it's slated for 4.4, which is due by the end of the year (November or December).