# Searching multiple tags and adding jQuery dependant script onto page template?

Tags: jquery, templates, javascript, tags, wp-enqueue-script

I have this simple javascript file for checking boxes in a tree view menu:

### treeview.js

```
$(".acidjs-css3-treeview").delegate("label input:checkbox", "change", function() {
    var
        checkbox = $(this),
        selectNestedListCheckbox = checkbox.parents("li").children("label").children("input"),
        siblingCheckboxes = checkbox.parentsUntil("ul","li").children("label").children("input");

    if(checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        return selectNestedListCheckbox.prop("checked", true);
    }
   selectNestedListCheckbox.prop("checked", false);
});
```

I have this as my WP template file:

### template

```
get_header(); ?>


<?php
//create right sidebar template
kleo_switch_layout('right');
?>

<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-title-section'); ?>

<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-before-wrap'); ?>

<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    // Start the Loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- Begin the Treeview menu -->
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search…" maxlength="50" required="required" />
    </div>
    <p>Refine search to posts containing chosen tags:</p>
<div class="acidjs-css3-treeview">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-0" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0">node-0</label>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-0-0" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0">node-0-0</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-0-0-0" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-0">node-0-0-0</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-0-0-1" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-1">node-0-0-1</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-1" /><span></span></label><label for="node-1">node-1</label>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-1-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-1-0" /><span></span></label><label for="node-1-0">node-1-0</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-1-0-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-1-0-0" /><span></span></label><label for="node-1-0-0">node-1-0-0</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-1-0-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-1-0-1" /><span></span></label><label for="node-1-0-1">node-1-0-1</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- End the Treeview menu -->
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/assets/js/treeview.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );

?>

        <?php
        /*
         * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
         * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
         * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
         */
        get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
        ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'page-parts/posts-social-share' ); ?>

        <?php if ( sq_option( 'page_comments', 0 ) == 1 ): ?>

            <!-- Begin Comments -->
            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
            <!-- End Comments -->

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile;

endif;
?>

<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-after-wrap'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The idea of this template is to allow the user to do a search based on a search term, and select multiple tags to filter the results.

I have a tree view menu setup, so that if the user selects a child tag, it would automatically select all of its ancestors as well.

[Here is a jFiddle of what the menu would look and function like ideally.](http://jsfiddle.net/davellan/uzufpjke/2/)

### Problems

1. The javascript is not executing, so the ancestors are not being checked when a child is checked.
2. The search is not functioning properly. It returns a query string as such:

> The URL would show http://example.com/?s=searchterm&tag[]=key-word1&tag[]=key-word2

This would result in the tags not being filtered. [I found this particular code for searching multiple tags here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199240/allow-visitors-to-search-by-multiple-tags-specific-ids) That link seems to suggest this won't work until WP 4.4 comes around. Any way of getting this working under current WP 4.3.1?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_scripts` fires on the `wp_head` action, you should move that code into your `functions.php` file. the action has already happened when you try to add your function to it. also, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` for the child theme uri instead of constructing it manually with `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Comment: @Milo - I would only need this script for this one page. Is there a way I could load only for this template?

Comment: Also, I made the changes you said (moved the wp_enqueue code into my functions.php, usde get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and javascript still not working. In the console, I get an error "TypeError: $ is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery is loaded in "noconflict" mode by wordpress. To use it, you need to replace the $ sign with "jQuery".

Answer (score 0):

After following Milo's advice, I needed to replace $ with jQuery as follows:

### treeview.js

```
jQuery(".acidjs-css3-treeview").delegate("label input:checkbox", "change", function() {
    var
        checkbox = jQuery(this),
        selectNestedListCheckbox = checkbox.parents("li").children("label").children("input"),
        siblingCheckboxes = checkbox.parentsUntil("ul","li").children("label").children("input");

    if(checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        return selectNestedListCheckbox.prop("checked", true);
    }
   selectNestedListCheckbox.prop("checked", false);
});
});
```

I moved the enqueue code to the functions.php file as follows:

### functions.php

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/assets/js/treeview.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

So then my template html was reduced to this:

### template

```
get_header(); ?>


<?php
//create right sidebar template
kleo_switch_layout('right');
?>

<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-title-section'); ?>

<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-before-wrap'); ?>

<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    // Start the Loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- Begin the Treeview menu -->
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search…" maxlength="50" required="required" />
    </div>
    <p>Refine search to posts containing chosen tags:</p>
<div class="acidjs-css3-treeview">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-0" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0">node-0</label>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-0-0" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0">node-0-0</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-0-0-0" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-0">node-0-0-0</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-0-0-1" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-1">node-0-0-1</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-1" /><span></span></label><label for="node-1">node-1</label>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-1-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-1-0" /><span></span></label><label for="node-1-0">node-1-0</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-1-0-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-1-0-0" /><span></span></label><label for="node-1-0-0">node-1-0-0</label></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="node-1-0-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="node-1-0-1" /><span></span></label><label for="node-1-0-1">node-1-0-1</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- End the Treeview menu -->
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

        <?php
        /*
         * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
         * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
         * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
         */
        get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
        ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'page-parts/posts-social-share' ); ?>

        <?php if ( sq_option( 'page_comments', 0 ) == 1 ): ?>

            <!-- Begin Comments -->
            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
            <!-- End Comments -->

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile;

endif;
?>

<?php get_template_part('page-parts/general-after-wrap'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

With these modifications, now the javascript runs properly. I still need a fix for the tag search, but I will ask another question for that issue.